# Why do we link the curl library even after including it as a header file?

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main()
{
    CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.example.com")
    return 0;
}
```

When compiling:

```
gcc foo.c -lcurl
```

Why does this error get returned if the curl library isn't included ?:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cclp7KeN.o: in function `main':
foo.c:(.text+0x157): undefined reference to `curl_easy_init'
/usr/bin/ld: foo.c:(.text+0x17f): undefined reference to `curl_easy_setopt'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code needed to do stuff (curl stuff, print stuff, scan stuff, math stuff, etc) is not written by or specified by the core language. That code is written by compiler writers (more correctly: library writers). They write the code, compile it and add the output (the executable instructions for your processor/OS) to libraries. You then have to include that specific library to create your executable with the functionality you want. Adding the `#include ...` is just text, just information to the compiler how to interface with the code already in the library. By default `libc` is auto included.

Answer (score 2):

You include the declarations (#define, enum, union, struct, union, typedef and function signatures) but link in the definition (implementation; library that has been compiled for you already).  For the code you posted above `int main();` would be declaration, it's a function signature and doesn't do anything as is, and `int main() { ... }` is your definition.

Comment: So including the headers is just like writing the prototypes for functions that are below main. right ?

Answer (score 1):

Including the header file in the source file tells the compiler where to get declarations of functions and objects in the curl library.

Including the library file in the command line tells the linker where to get the object module that contains the definitions of the functions and objects in the curl library.

(The `gcc` command does not do compiling or linking itself. It calls other executables to do those and/or other functions, and which it does depends on the switches and arguments passed to it.)

Comment: So including the headers is just like writing the prototypes for functions that are below main. right ?

Comment: @a_coder: Including the header includes the contents of that file as if they had been written in the source file. Declarations do not have to be below `main`. In fact, a declaration for an identifier must appear before the identifier is used. Many people put the definitions (declarations of functions are definitions if they include the code for the function) after `main` and non-definition declarations (declarations without the code) before `main`, but there is no requirement to do that. You an put the definitions of functions above `main`.

Comment: The header file is just c source code, and you will see curl/easy.h has these two lines `CURL_EXTERN CURL *curl_easy_init(void);` and  `CURL_EXTERN CURLcode curl_easy_setopt(CURL *curl, CURLoption option, ...);`

Answer (score 0):

The header only contains things like macro definitions, type definitions, and function *declarations* - it does not contain the actual source code for the library.

The code for the library has already been compiled and packaged in a separate binary which can either be statically linked against your program or loaded at runtime (depending on your needs).

Think of the header as defining the *interface* for the library - you still have to link against its *implementation*.